# Check user last login date

Tags: php, plugin-development, login

I need to show to the user a password change page at first login and ever month. Is there any hook or filter that can I use to check in my plugin code when the user have done last login?

Comment: You could use the [`wp_login`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/) hook to add/check/update user metadata indicating the most recent login time (using [`add_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/) / [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) / [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)).

Comment: @PatJ thank you. I'm at the moment checking an user meta field to check if the user account is activated, and this action is done from a particulare user role I've defined. I'm using the `wp_login` hook to check this, I will consider to do also the first login check after the account is activated. If you leave an answer with an example I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're more interested in the last time the user reset their password than the last time they logged in. I've written this to check on the last password reset.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpse410045_check_last_login', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Checks and updates the user's last login time.
 *
 * @param string  $user_login The username.
 * @param WP_User $user       The user object.
 */
function wpse410045_check_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    $now        = time();
    $single     = true;
    $last_reset = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_prefix_last_password_reset', $single );
    // If the user meta hasn't been set, use 0.
    if ( empty( $last_reset ) ) {
        $last_reset = 0;
    }
    if ( $now > ( absint( $last_reset + MONTH_IN_SECONDS ) ) {
            // However you choose to do this.
            require_user_password_reset();
    }
}

add_action( 'after_password_reset', 'wpse_410045_update_password_meta', 10 );
/**
 * Updates the time of the password reset for a user.
 *
 * @param WP_User $user The user whose password has been reset.
 */
function wpse_410045_update_password_meta( $user ) {
    // Updates the "last password reset" meta to the present time.
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_prefix_last_password_reset', time() );
}
```

### Update

From the comments below: If you're using the `login_redirect` filter, you should be able to check for the last password change and redirect the user if their password has "expired".

Replace the first part of the answer above with something like this (I'm assuming you've got a URL where you'll want to redirect your users to actually change their passwords; I use `/my-password-change` in the code.)

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse410045_check_password_age', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Checks the user's last password change. Redirects if it's over a month old.
 *
 * @param string  $redirect   The destination URL.
 * @param string  $requested_redirect The requested destination URL.
 * @param WP_User $user       The user object.
 */
function wpse410045_check_last_login( $redirect, $requested_redirect, $user ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        // Something went wrong, bail out.
        return $redirect;
    }
    $now        = time();
    $single     = true;
    $last_reset = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_prefix_last_password_reset', $single );
    // If the user meta hasn't been set, use 0.
    if ( empty( $last_reset ) ) {
        $last_reset = 0;
    }
    if ( $now > ( absint( $last_reset + MONTH_IN_SECONDS ) ) {
            // Redirect to the password change URL.
            return '/my-password-change';
    }
    // Otherwise, carry on.
    return $redirect;
}
```

The `after_password_reset` action should still be fine.

### References

- [`wp_login` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/)
- [`after_password_reset` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_password_reset/)
- [`login_redirect` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/)
- [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)
- [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)

Comment: I will follow your suggestion. If I understand correctly, I need to add a field into user meta table whan I create the user account and than check for it when the user do the login right? In this way I will have the first login check to force user change the password and the check every x days to force user to change the password right?

Comment: just a question, where do you get the `MONTH_IN_SECONDS` costant?

Comment: I also checked my code and I'm using the `login_redirect` filter to redirect users based on the role. Can I do the check for the password also into that function and update the meta after that the user logged in forst time with a custom rest route?

Comment: `MONTH_IN_SECONDS` is a constant defined by WordPress, along with a few others. See [this Codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Easier_Expression_of_Time_Constants). I'll update my answer re: the `login_redirect` filter.

Comment: thank you for the article suggestion. I will try your solution. I saw another similar post where the user used the `DateTime` class to check the difference between two dates. Is there any difference from checking using `time()` and `DateTime` ?

Comment: `time()` just gets you the current # of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. [`DateTime`](https://php.net/DateTime) is a class with many methods which will allow you to (among other things) do calculations on dates. It's up to you how you implement your solution.

Comment: ok, thank you for the help :)